# How can I unchecked parent node if checked any child node in ztree?

Tags: jquery, ztree

Now in ztree, if checked any child node then it checked it's parent node also, but I want not to check it's parent node. Is there any way ?

```
var setting = {
        view: {
            dblClickExpand: true,
            selectedMulti: false,
            showLine: false,
            nameIsHTML: true,

        },
        check: {
            enable: true,                
        },
        data: {
            simpleData: {
                enable: true
            }
        },           
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [documentation](http://www.treejs.cn/v3/api.php):

> setting.check.chkboxType:
>
> When one node is checked or unchecked, control its parent node and its child node auto checked or unchecked. It is valid when [setting.check.enable = true & setting.check.chkStyle = "checkbox"]
>
> Default: { "Y": "ps", "N": "ps" }

Hence, I suggest to use:

```
check: {
     enable: true,
    chkboxType: { "Y": "s", "N": "s" }
},
```

```js
var setting = {
    view: {
        dblClickExpand: true,
        selectedMulti: false,
        showLine: false,
        nameIsHTML: true,

    },
    check: {
        enable: true,
        chkboxType: { "Y": "s", "N": "s" }
    },
    data: {
        simpleData: {
            enable: true
        }
    }
};
var zTreeObj;
var zNodes = [
    {name:"test1", open:true, children:[
        {name:"test1_1"}, {name:"test1_2"}]},
    {name:"test2", open:true, children:[
        {name:"test2_1"}, {name:"test2_2"}]}
];

zTreeObj = $.fn.zTree.init($("#treeDemo"), setting, zNodes);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/zTree/zTree_v3@master/css/demo.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/zTree/zTree_v3@master/css/zTreeStyle/zTreeStyle.css" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/zTree/zTree_v3@master/js/jquery.ztree.all.js"></script>


<div>
    <ul id="treeDemo" class="ztree"></ul>
</div>
```